# $post in a string?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$_POST['aantal'] = 4;
$_POST['begin'] = 10;

$iets = $_POST['aantal'] + $_POST['begin'];
$ietsanders = $iets - 1;
$values = "'$_POST[a" . $_POST['begin'] . "]', " ;

for ($i = $_POST['begin'] + 1 ; $i < $ietsanders ; $i++){
    $values = $values . "'$_POST[a" .$i. "]', ";
}
$values = $values."'$_POST[a" . $ietsanders . "]', ";
echo "using  ".$values;
?>
```

This is my code; what's wrong? It gives me an error at:

```
$values = $values . "'$_POST[a" .$i. "]', ";
```

and:

```
$values = $values."'$_POST[a" . $ietsanders . "]', ";
```

It gives me no error when I leave away the `'` at `'$_POST`. I want my for loop to give me `'$_POST[a$i]'` every run:

```
'$_POST[a10]', '$_POST[a11]', '$_POST[a12]', '$_POST[a13]',
```

Comment: You need to read up on the difference between single and double quotes, and how concentanation works.

Comment: Also read up on database escaping or more contemporary methods (PDO, prepared statements). And rather use arrays for the input instead of looking for indexes yourself.

Comment: Please! Avoid injections: `$post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the string `'a'` with `$_POST['begin']` as in index to the outer `$_POST`, as in:

```
$_POST['a' . $_POST['begin']]
```

Your loop looks then like:

```
// Concatenate a single quote with the $_POST dynamic key, then another single quote and comma.
$values = "'" . $_POST['a' . $_POST['begin']] ."', " ;

// In the loop, same thing concatenating single quotes around the $_POST key
// dynamically built with $i
for ($i = $_POST['begin'] + 1 ; $i < $ietsanders ; $i++){
    $values = $values . "'" . $_POST['a' .$i] . "', ";
}
```

The way you were attempting to do it by building up the `$_POST['stuff']` as strings, would require a call to `eval()`, which is *not to be done under most any circumstances* when accepting user input like `$_POST`.

If you are intending to pass these values from `$_POST` to a SQL query, you will need to be performing some protection against SQL injection on them. If possible, it is recommended to switch to an API supporting prepared statements instead.

Finally, Not sure why you are *writing* to the `$_POST` superglobal.  Hopefully you have a good reason to do this:

```
$_POST['aantal'] = 4;
$_POST['begin'] = 10;
```

#### Update after comments:

Well, it turns out the idea is to build the *literal* string `'$_POST[a10]', '$_POST[a11]', '$_POST[a12]', '$_POST[a13]',` rather than to interpolate the values from it.  To do that, the string should be single-quoted to prevent the `$` from delimiting variables.

```
// Single quote the string, and escape single quotes inside it
$values = '\'$_POST[a' . $_POST['begin'] . ']\', ';

// In the loop, same thing concatenating single quotes around the $_POST key
// dynamically built with $i
for ($i = $_POST['begin'] + 1 ; $i < $ietsanders ; $i++){
    $values = $values . '\'$_POST[a' . $i .']\', ';
}

// After the loop, you have an extra comma and space at the end. trim() it off
$values = trim($values, ', ');
```

[Here's a working example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/s5wTai)

Comment: thats not want i mean, i want the $_POST also in the echo.. =\

Comment: @user1834161 What do you mean? You want the _literal_ string `$_POST` in your output, rather than the values from `$_POST`?

Comment: @user1834161 In other words, are you actually trying to build the string `'$_POST[a10]', '$_POST[a11]', '$_POST[a12]', '$_POST[a13]', ` for output or display, rather than to interpolate the variable values?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
 $values = $values . "\'$_POST[a" .$i. "]\', ";
```